# What is the best way in Kotlin to create a unique ID for each object I create?

Tags: kotlin

### My program includes a class:

```
class Player (private var playerName: String,
                  private var playerSkill: Int,
                  private var playerType: String) {


        var playerID = 0

      }
```

I'm instantiating the object when the user wants to create a new player, and my question is what is the best way to create a unique ID (i.e. playerID) for each player. 
e.g. playerID[0] = 0, playerID[1] = 1 and so on...... 
The purpose is to later store the Players in an Array of Players and to be able to get to each player by his ID.

Thanks.

Comment: just create a global integer variable and increment it whenever it's read

Comment: Unique within what scope?  Unique within a single game (however that's defined)?  Unique within a single run of the app?  Unique for all runs on a particular machine?  Unique for every run of the app anywhere in the world, at any time?

Comment: Please don't create a global variable of any kind, but a factory object would probably be appropriate.

Comment: UUID could help in assigning unique IDs.

Comment: Answer to gidds: Unique so that each player assigned to the application as a player will have a unique ID. That ID should be saved and differentiate one player from the other

Answer (score 7):

There's a few options you could use, but before we get into your options, **beware mutability!** I've noticed that all of the properties of your class are mutable. Unless there is good reason for this, it's worthwhile making them immutable; for example:

```kotlin
class Player (
    private val playerName: String,
    private val playerSkill: Int,
    private val playerType: String,
    val playerID: Int = 0,
)
```

Note the subtle change from `var` (mutable) to `val` (immutable), and also this moves the `playerID` property to the constructor, rather than setting the value once the player instance has been created.

Now, to your options...

**1. Using a global state (probably the worst idea):**

```kotlin
object GlobalState {
    private var value = 0;

    fun getNextInt(): Int = value++
}

val player = Player("John", 123, "SomePlayerType", GlobalState.getNextInt())
```

Reasons this isn't the best idea:

1. It relies on a global state (bad practice).
2. The global state is mutable.
3. The global state will reset to zero every time you restart your application.

**2. Change the playerID type to UUID**

UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers) contain 128-bits of entropy and it's generally considered highly unlikely that a random UUID will ever be created twice (of course, it's possible, just unlikely).

```kotlin
class Player (
    private val playerName: String,
    private val playerSkill: Int,
    private val playerType: String,
    val playerID: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
)

val player = Player("John", 123, "SomePlayerType")
```

Considerations:

1. It does not rely on global state.
2. They don't reset to zero, so better over app restarts or when using persistence.

**3. Use a data class**

Data classes are designed to be used when your classes have value semantics, rather than behaviour semantics. They implement `equals` and `hashCode` for you. This implementation would work best on the assumption that `playerName`, `playerSkill` and `playerType` are unique for each player:

```kotlin
data class Player (
    private val playerName: String,
    private val playerSkill: Int,
    private val playerType: String
) {
    val playerID: Int get() = hashCode()
}
```

Considerations:

1. It does not rely on global state.
2. Promotes value semantics in your class.
3. Allows `Player` instances to work correctly in `Set` collections.

**4. Combination of UUID and data classes (recommended):**

```kotlin
data class Player (
    private val playerName: String,
    private val playerSkill: Int,
    private val playerType: String,
    val playerID: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
)
```

Considerations:

1. It does not rely on global state.
2. Promotes value semantics in your class.
3. Allows Player instances to work correctly in `Set` collections.
4. Works just fine over app restarts and in persistence.

Comment: Is the GlobalState solution thread safe as written? I think a better solution might be to just use `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`'s `incrementAndGet` or `getAndIncrement`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is from the docs
`var uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()`
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: The question is asking for an `Int` ID, not a `String`.